# extend array by n numbers while repeating elements

Tags: ruby

If I have an array like this

```
[1,2,3]*2 
#=> [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

But I want to do it to certain length, that length is 1.5 the original array, preferably in one line

```
[1,2,3].size = 3
[1,2,3,1,2] or something like this
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: 5 is not 3 times 1.5.

Comment: Please share if you have tried other methods. `size` reports the number of elements. There is no `size=` method for an array. Do you want a single method, or are willing to accept an iteration answer?

Comment: Also, `[1, 2, 3]*2` results in `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`, not `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @engineersmnky please post this as an answer, providing steps along the way to help OP and others.

Comment: @HunterStevens Answer posted with modifications for the 1.5 times original size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple solution in one line

```
 ([1,2,3]*2).tap {|a| a.pop(a.size - (a.size / 2 * 1.5)) }
 #=> [1,2,3,1,2]
```

Breakdown

```
 ([1,2,3]*2)
 #=> [1,2,3,1,2,3]
 #`Object#tap` will yield the object itself to the block 
 #so a is [1,2,3,1,2,3]
 .tap { |a|
   #pop is mutating so we are dropping the elements that are after 
   #the array size minus 1.5 times the original array of [1,2,3]  
   #so this becomes [1,2,3,1,2,3].pop(6 - 4.5)
   #pop will use the Integer value so this becomes (6 - 4.5).to_i (which is 1)   
   a.pop(a.size - (a.size / 2 * 1.5)) 
 }  
 #=> [1,2,3,1,2]
```

I prefer @sawa's answer using an enumerator but it does require 2 lines.

Also this seems very strange and if you offered more information about the actual problem there are possibly better ways to solve this.

**Update**: I think this is a bit cleaner

Similar concept using tap but without the need to multiply and then divide

```
[1,2,3].tap {|a| a.concat(a.take((a.size * 0.5).round)) }
#=> [1,2,3,1,2]
```

Breakdown:

```
#concat will take an array and append the elements to the end of the reciever
#so here we are taking half of the original elements (rounded up) 
#and appending them to the original array
[1,2,3].tap {|a|
  #a.take(3 * 0.5) with round becomes a.take(2)
  #a.concat([1,2])
  # => [1,2,3,1,2] 
  a.concat(a.take((a.size * 0.5).round)) 
}
#=> [1,2,3,1,2]
```

Other options if you know the number of elements you want then it becomes very simple

```
[1,2,3].cycle.take(5)
#=> [1,2,3,1,2]
```

Comment: technically, yours is two lines. @sawa can make it a single line by explicitly calling the array, not the object it is held under.

Comment: If `a` is the array and `n=1.5`, doesn't `sz = n*a.size; (a*sz.ceil).first(sz.round)` read better?

Comment: @HunterStevens both examples are single line but for clarification as requested by you I split the breakdowns into multi-line. Also sawa cannot make his one line because `cycle` creates an `Enumerator` which has no  size and thus cannot be referenced when multiplying by 1.5

Comment: @CarySwoveland not sure I understand the question. While `a` is the array `#tap` will return the receiver so we have to mutate the receiver for `#tap` to return the correct object. `#first` does not mutate so using it inside of `#tap` will have no impact on the return. Also I find semi-colons in single line blocks to be more confusing than helpful. If I need to use a semi-colon I'd rather use 2 lines. I will however concede to your comment on sawa's post as `(a.size * 0.5).round` is a little clearer.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.cycle.first(a.length.*(1.5).round)
# => [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Can you just briefly explain that round was needed because you can not have a partial array element?

Comment: Very elegant solution. The methods are easy to understand -- to documentation needs to be linked.

Comment: You don't need `.to_enum` and `(a.length*1.5).round` is perhaps less obscure than `length.*`. –